# How to fix font issue on gimp with x11 or macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro

I just installed gimp 2.60 in my macbook pro but my gimp appears in Nepalese font instead of English. How to solve it ?

[image: screen shot or effect]

Comment: where did you get it from?

Comment: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html version 2.6

Answer (score 1):

GIMP [automatically detects](http://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-fire-up.html#gimp-concepts-running-language) and uses the system language.

In the unlikely event that language detection fails, or if you just want to use a different language, you may do so:

Apple Mac OS X

```
From System Preferences, click on the International icon.
```

In the Language tab, the desired language should be **the first** in the list.

- recent builds of GIMP may offer a language selection in the preferences

Comment: after keeping only English in that list, it appeared in English, Thank you very much. Is that recent builds of GIMP works with Mac OS X 10.5.8 system ?

Comment: great we can check this as done than !